# ngResource: Custom update method cleans the instance

Tags: angularjs, ngresource

I make this `Customer` service with `$resource`:

```
.factory('Customer', function($resource, apiURL){
    return $resource(apiURL+'customers/:id', { id: '@id' }, {
        'update': {method: 'PUT'}
    })
})
```

When I update the `customer` (*that is a Instance of `Customer` service*), and after the *promise* is resolved, the `customer` var is cleaned. Why?

```
$scope.customer = Customer.get({id: $stateParams.id}, function (){
    console.log($scope.customer) // Object {id: 1, name: 'John Doe', ...}
    $scope.customer.$update()
        .then(function () {
            console.log($scope.customer) // Object { status: true, $promise: Object, $resolved: true }
        })
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I update the customer (that is a Instance of Customer service), and after the promise is resolved, the customer var is cleaned. Why?

When the `$update` resolves it clears and updates the `$resource` object with the new data. Your server is returning empty data.

If you want to update without clearing the object, put the updated object in the second argument of the `Customer.update` method.

```
Customer.update({id: $stateParams.id}, $scope.customer);
```

Or modify your server to return the updated information.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a simple service with `json-server` (https://github.com/typicode/json-server) based on a JSON file:

```
{
  "customers": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "John Doe",
      "age": 25
    }
  ]
}
```

I also copy-pasted your code (the only change I did was to use `1` instead of `$stateParams.id`) and tested it with the above service and angular-resource v1.4.8. There was no such problem - both console logs showed exactly the same output. Maybe the issue is caused by server-side code? I can't think of any reason why this would not work in Angular (except for older version of angular-resource).

**Update**

Your `PUT` method on the service should not only update customer on the server, but also return the updated object. If it doesn't, your $scope.customer is substituted with empty object which is returned from the service.